# Элементы flex-wrap: wrap; превращаются в список, при прописывании padding, но необходимо чтобы отзывы шли в строку, а не в список

Tags: html, css, flexbox

CSS:

```css
.clients {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.clients__item {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 20px 0 175px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}


.clients__photo {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;

    border-radius: 50%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.clients__name {
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.clients__prof {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.clients__text {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #999;
}

.clients__text:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 15px 0;

    background-color: #f38181;
}

.section--clients {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background: url("clients-bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
 HTML:

<section class="section section--clients">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="section_header">
            <h3 class="section_subtitle">For all devices</h3>
            <h2 class="section_title">Unique design</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="clients">
            <div class="clients__item">
                <img class="clients__photo" src="http://placehold.it/110" alt="">
                <div class="clients__content">
                    <div class="clients__name">Matthew Dix</div>
                    <div class="clients__prof">Graphic Design</div>
                    <div class="clients__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clients__item">
                <img class="clients__photo" src="http://placehold.it/110" alt="">
                <div class="clients__content">
                    <div class="clients__name">Nick Karvounis</div>
                    <div class="clients__prof">Graphic Design</div>
                    <div class="clients__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clients__item">
                <img class="clients__photo" src="http://placehold.it/110" alt="">
                <div class="clients__content">
                    <div class="clients__name">Jaelynn Castillo </div>
                    <div class="clients__prof">Graphic Design</div>
                    <div class="clients__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clients__item">
                <img class="clients__photo" src="http://placehold.it/110" alt="">
                <div class="clients__content">
                    <div class="clients__name">Mike Petrucci</div>
                    <div class="clients__prof">Graphic Design</div>
                    <div class="clients__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден:

```
client_item: box-sizing: border-box
```